# How to load a file from a separate assembly in a MonoTouch application?

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, nunit

I have a MonoTouch solution with a few projects in it. One of the projects is an executable project. It has a SQLite3 database file that is ./Resources/db.sqlite3. It is set to BundleResource in it's properties. Then, I have a test project for the first one.

Is there any way to load the database of the first project from within the test project?  Other than copying the database file to the test project, which isn't ideal, I have not found a way.

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("db", "sqlite3");
```

does not find anything from within the test project.

Looking through the test project inside of

```
/Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/{GUID}/Test.app/
```

I do not see the actual project assembly, just aliases to it. This is seems to be how it is supposed to be since it can still access the class files and all of the non-database tests pass.

Googling has not turned anything up; searching on here has not either, just loading things from within the assembly you are already in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In going through and attempting svn's suggestions, a coworker and I noticed that you can add a link to an existing file in a project.

We left everything thing the same in the app project. Then in the test project:

1. Right click on a folder and select Add->Add Files...
2. Select the database file from the app project
3. Click OK
4. In the popup select "Add a link to the file"
5. Click OK

The test project now has a link to the db.sqlite3 file and all of our database tests pass.

Thanks for guiding us towards the solution.

Also, I'd like to note that I did not create a folder named Resources, I know that it is reserved, I am just using it to hold a copy of the database. It's getting copied to and used from /Documents so that we can write to it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot share files across iOS applications - at least not on devices.

You can hack around this, with the simulator, if you know (e.g. use an absolute path) or guess the path of the file(s) you want.

**Keep in mind that won't work if you want to execute (or test) this on devices.**

> I do not see the actual project assembly, just aliases to it.

In some cases (and only on the simulator) MonoTouch will use *symlinks* instead of copying the files. That makes edit/build/debug cycles faster on the simulator.

Comment: We had set that aside as our last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of 'Resources' as a foldername is not recommended and can give problems.
ALso you should set the build action to 'Content'

In the main app project reference the project that contains to file. Instantiate at least one class/object from the project that contains the db file. This can be a dummy class. Now the compiler will copy all content from the referenced project with build action 'Content' to the app bundle when compiling.

Comment: Did you try in your test app
System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "db/sqlite3");

Comment: Strange, I often use 'Content' marked files from library projects and that works fine. Maybe it doens't work because it is an executable project? Then putting the db in a separate ios library project should solve it

Comment: ah, yeah that is probably the difference. It used to be in a library project, but got refactored into the executable. It worked just fine when it was in the library project.